# Function to get rows from DB by multiple columns conditionally

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, node-postgres

So lets say I have a `GET` route for `/movies` (it's not actually movies but it would be easier to explain this way)

On client side I have a table that I want to filter movies depending on dropdown menus:

Genre, Year, Country, Type (By default they all are on `ALL`)

Those are also columns on the db for the `movies` table. I am using [node-postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)

So my query would be like this:

```
  const query = {
    text: 'SELECT * FROM movies WHERE genre = $1 AND year = $2 AND country = $3 AND type = $4',
    values: [genre, year, country, type],
  };
```

But that doesn't work if the user don't choose anything from the dropdown (it would be `ALL`)

What would be the best way to do this so if the client sends `ALL` it just don't add that column to the query?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have no choice, you should only put your conditions if they are applicables...

For example:

```
const params = {
    genre: null,
    year: 2015,
    country: null,
    type: 'western',
};

const query = {
    text: 'SELECT * FROM movies',
    values: Object.values(params).filter(x => x),
};

if (Object.values(params).filter(x => x).length) {
    query.text += ' WHERE '
    let i = 1;
    for (const param of Object.keys(params).filter(x => params[x])) {
        query.text += `${param} = $${i} AND `
        i++;
    }
    query.text = query.text.substr(0, query.text.length - 5);
}

console.log(query); // {"text":"SELECT * FROM movies WHERE year = $1 AND type = $2","values":[2015,"western"]}
```

Hope it helps.